# Automatic command when closing terminal

Tags: unix

this one might be unusual, but I'm lazy and curious.

I know it is possible to have automatic commands when the terminal is open (written in the .bashrc or .profile). But is it possible to have an automatic command whenever the terminal is closed?

I would like emitting the command: "disown -a" always before closing my terminals (to let background jobs run in a server).

Cheers,
Ricardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a `trap` inside `~/.bashrc`. Here is an example snippet that you can put inside your `~/.bashrc`

```
function goodbye
{
    # Your cleanup code...
    echo "goodbye !"
    sleep 1
}
trap goodbye EXIT
```

It would print `goodbye!` before exiting the terminal. Other commands would work the same way.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much!